# Carousel spacing in BotFramework

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to display a set of adaptive cards in a carousel on Bot Framework.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGifK.jpg) image shows what I have achieved. As carousels are not a part of adaptive cards, I was wondering if it was possible to modify the spacing between 2 adaptive cards in a carousel. Can the spacing be increased, decreased, or removed in some way?

Comment: Which channel(s) are you using or plan to use?

Comment: Bot framework Web Chat

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for webchat (Botchat.css) you can change this property and will adjust the spacing of the carousel, the `4px` value is the one you would have to change

```
.wc-carousel .wc-hscroll > ul > li {
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

Note that you would not be able to use the webchat iFrame and would have to use webchat via [this method](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline)